# Azure SQL - Timeout reached

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a capacity test running on a S4 Azure database, and I am getting this error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I have 500 "users" hitting my site. My connectionstring is this

> Server=tcp:database.net,1433;Initial Catalog=database-prd;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

I have checked my code and what I do is:

**Using "using"**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();
  //... logic
}
```

**Scoped repository**

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IRepository, SqlServerRepository>();
```

I am now thinking of the default Max Pool Size. I haven't set it on the connectionstring. Should I do this? I have an S4, and the properties is:

1. Max concurrent sessions: 4800
2. Max concurrent Workers (requests): 200

according to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases#standard-service-tier-continued

What should I set the pool size to? Does it even matter? As I have understand it "Max Pool Size" is a client side and it defaults to 100. I could try to raise it a bit to maybe 500 or 800.

Where it max out is on some pretty simple selects

```
select p1,p2,p3 from baskets where Id=1234
```

and the same for the lines. Not to complex. The only complex query I have has like 4 or 5 joins, but it is not hit that much.

Do anyone here have some points to Max Pool Size? Does it even matter?

Comment: I think the default pool size is 100, and if you have more connections you need a larger pool.

Comment: @DavidG, yes. I will try this. As I understand it, i could potentially have 4800 sessions to my database, but should i then set my pool size to 4800? I have diffuculty understanding the relations between sessions and Pool Size. If there is any at all.